# Yii2 rest api + админка на js + фронт на js

Tags: yii2, rest

На основе basic шаблона сделал апи. Админка и сам сайт будут на angular. Проблема в том что для приложения с которым будет взаимодействовать пользователь, нужно оставить доступными только actionIndex и actionView. Для админки сделать все доступным только после авторизации. Собственно вопрос - можно ли разрулить как то все это в одном backend приложении и использовать общие контроллеры/модели и для приложения админки и для приложения сайта или придется делать два backend приложения - одно для админки и одно для сайта ? Просто оба они будут на js, следовательно запросы будут к апи, поэтому не уверен есть ли смысл плодить два почти одинаковых rest бэкенда.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю тут может решить вопрос распределения ролей. те для гостя и авторизованного пользователя настраиваются правила доступа только get запросов.

НО. изначально не правильно совмещать админку и сам сайт в одном коде... Как правило для них настраиваются отдельные пользователи для бд (к примеру что бы для сайта при подключеннии к бд был доступ только к чтению таблиц и то не всех. А в админке большинство привелегий) И тд. По мимо этого в админке возможно расширение функционала (и как правило этот функционал не должен быть доступен с самого сайта)

В общем решать вам. Если решите делать все таки в бэйсик то копайте в сторону Rbac и before action... Возможно прописать всю обработку в само конфиге а не писать в каждом контроллере.

Пример:

```
'as beforeRequest' => [
    'class' => 'backend\modules\Authorization\models\AccessControl',
    'rules' => [
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'actions' => ['login'],
        ],
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['@'],
        ],
    ],
    'denyCallback' => function () {
        echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'msg' => 'not login']);
    },
],
```

backend\modules\Authorization\models\AccessControl Самописный функционал:

```
class AccessControl extends ActionFilter
```